# R markdown blastula format issues

Tags: css, r, email, markdown, blastula

I'm trying to send a R markdown file as body in an email and having some formatting issues.

I'm a total beginner at CSS so I hope it's an easy fix, but it's driving me nuts.

I have the following CSS setup for the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  table {
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  table caption {
   color: rgb(241, 135, 0);
   font-size: 30px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  table tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: white;
 }
  table tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
 }
  table th {
   background-color: rgb(198, 198, 198);
   color: white;
   font-weight: normal;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   padding: 20px 30px;
   text-align: left;
   word-break: keep-all;
  }
  table td {
   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
   font-size: 14px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   padding: 20px 30px;
   text-align: left;
   word-break: keep-all;
  }
```

If I then convert the R Markdown file with blastula::render_email to an email (output of .Rmd file is set to blastula::blastula_email) it all looks great:

[image]

When sending the email however, the last letter(s) of column names & fields are wrapped into a new line:

[image]

How can I prevent those letters being wrapped?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for:

```
table th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```